# How can I use Node's request library from within a webpage through a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, request

I want my chrome extension to look at a page's HTML elements, find a user's Facebook id, and communicate with AWS. I set up my project so far using `yo`'s [chrome extension generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-chrome-extension). From there, I wrote a little content-script that starts messing with other page's DOM, changing swear words into nice words.

I am having trouble importing [request](https://github.com/request/request) into my project. How can I import it into my Content-Script?

I tried this:
`var request = require('request');` after doing a `npm install --save request` but I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better of simply using the built in APIs, in this case a normal XHR should work. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

I'm not familiar with the yo generator you referenced, but if it's not using jspm/webpack/browserify or something similar I think you are out of luck installing npm packages. You could try setting one of them up manualy, but chrome has some restrictions not found on the normal web, so many packages would probably end up breaking.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give XHR a shot

Comment: Could I send a POST request with headers and a json body?

Comment: In a content script you can use the same thing as you can on a normal website. So yes, you can, but I think you'd have to be aware of CORS. Think of content scripts as script files included directly into the site with a <script> tag.

Comment: @HenrikKarlsson That would be a very bad misconception. Content scripts bypass CORS requirements [according to host permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr#requesting-permission) just like the rest of the extension and in general behave very differently from page's own scripts in terms of [execution environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) and [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#interactions).